# iOS Deploying exception on runtime : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no webview in java.library.path

Tags: maven, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

i have a JavaFX application and i am trying to make it run on iOS
it is running well in Android. Linux, Mac. but I just get a white screen on the iOS-simulator

i am not using java-modules.

i got this exception in the terminal

```
Exception in Application start method
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:202)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no webview in java.library.path
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:132)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:47)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
[Thu Sept 15 14:43:27 CEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<clinit>(WebView.java:112)
```

About the pom.xml (which is already ran well in Android)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxx.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.15</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.15</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.AppxxxxmainClassName>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>keyboard</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>keyboard</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                    <releaseConfiguration>
                        <bundleName>xxxx</bundleName>
                    </releaseConfiguration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios-sim</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios-sim</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Also, I tried

- Java *11 & 17*
- GraalVM *11 & 17*
- javaFX *18 & 19*
- iOS *Simulator & Real Device*

i am using this mvn command

```
 mvn -Pios-sim clean gluonfx:runagent gluonfx:build gluonfx:package gluonfx:install gluonfx:nativerun
```

All gave same results,

Comment: May this help, This is the beginning of graalvm logs

‘
[GVM] Starting GVM for ios
..determineCpuFeaures
..Sept 15, 2022 2:43:27 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
..WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4563e9ab'
..IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 0 view 0 pf otready 
..GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-19.4.3
..  initialize() returns 140517253880896
..IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 32ad5c0 view 0 pf otready 
..GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0

‘

Comment: Check the logs under `target/gluonfx`, and see if the `libjfxwebkit.a` is added to the link command?

Comment: no 

but i found this

-force_load,/Users/xxxx/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/ios-arm64/sdk/lib/libwebview.a

Comment: Right, that is because for iOS there is no WebKit, the JavaFX WebView just uses the native one. You say you tested a real device, do you have the same issue? Also, did you test on macOS, the exact same project?

Comment: yes, mac os is is working fine. when i do runagent it run in the mac peacfully. 
in the real device, yes i have the same problem, but in the real device i can not read the logss, but i can when i do in simulator

Comment: On macOS, also `mvn gluonfx:build gluonfx:nativerun` should work. On the iOS simulator, I can reproduce your issue. But on iOS device it works fine for me. Since you can't see the logs, it could be for a different reason.

Comment: I see the issue:  `~/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/ios-arm64/sdk/lib/libwebview.a` is linked only for arm64, not for x86_64, while the rest of the other libraries are for both. I've just filed an [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1171).

Comment: Nice, so we found a bug here, which is good. 
now i am trying to check how it is working in the real devices. Is there is a way to receive the exceptions, logs, 
why it is not working like android and in the terminal i receive the logs.
or do i made something wrong ??

Comment: If you deploy to your plugged  device, when you run `mvn -Píos gluonfx:nativerun` you should be able to get all the logs in your terminal and under the log folder.

Comment: The terminals stop give any updates, but the logs shows that there is an error behind that "[fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)]".

Comment: But this error is not appear on the mac nativerun. on mac nativerun i have a different error in the JS-Bridging !! i feel blue.

Comment: Also i want to tell you important note about the iOS installation, the installions as listed in the gluonfx docs is not running as expected. i had to install "brew install ios-deploy" first, Please if this is true (i think) we may need to update gluonfx doc for that  beside installing (libusbmuxd & libimobiledevice) to avoid problems for next users

Comment: I see, that is relevant, as GluonFX applies a [patch](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/util/ios/Deploy.java#L317) when installing `iOS-deploy`, precisely to enable receiving the logs from the terminal. That's why the docs don't ask to install it.

Comment: I see, also from this patch code I see the errors that I had because the patch couldn’t install it by itself , that’s why I installed it . I will uninstall it and I will try again. Thanks man,

Comment: FYI, if you use GluonFX 1.0.16-SNAPSHOT, the WebView should work now on your iOS Simulator. Just make sure you add a `pluginRepository` to your pom with this URL: `http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots`.

Comment: FYI: just feedback. it worked smoothly :)